# How to say "There was controversy surrounding the iPhone 7's release"

Tags: translation

How would one say "There was controversy surrounding the iPhone 7's release"—or more generally that there was controversy surrounding something. The word *diskutado*, or discussion seems to potentially work, currently I have "Estis diskutado pri la kreaĵo el iPhone 7".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was controversy surrounding (about) the event.

- Estis polemiko pri la okazo.

There was controversy because of the event.

- Estis polemiko pro la okazo.

Controversy happened due to the event.

- Polemiko okazis pro la okazo.

Answer (score 7):

„diskuto” laŭ mi ne estas sufiĉe forta. Mi dirus:

Estis disputo pri la lanĉo de iPhone 7s.

(Temas pri nur unu litero da diferenco, sed pri tute alia nuanco!)

Alia eblo: La lanĉo de iPhone 7s kaŭzis grandan polemikon.